# How to set a console encoding in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run ASP.NET Core server I get an encoding problem:
[image]

How to resolve this?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19837?

Comment: what is your source encoding? change to UTF-8 if not. like so: press F1 then type `Change File Encoding`
and select one of:
`Reopen with Encoding`
`Save with Encoding`